# Change CSS of another div when hover on Table cell

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have seen similar post on stack exchange where you can change css of another div when hovered over one div. However in my case it is not working as I am using this with a table cell.

Here, is the HTML code:

```css
body {
  padding: 5%;
}
.tbdata {
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tooltip {
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.tbdata:hover ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tbdata:hover ~ .tooltip:after {
  content: attr(data-);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tbdata" data-="This is the tooltip text for col1">This is table data1</td>
    <td class="tbdata" data-="This is the tooltip text for col2">This is table data2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="tooltip">
</div>
```

I want to make the `.tooltip` div visible when hovered over the `.tbdata` and also change the content using `attr()` from the table cell.

Please suggest.

Comment: can you use javascript or jquery?

Comment: you cannot do it using css, you should use javascript

Comment: actually the tilde character is used for the siblings and in this case tbody is not a sibling for the .tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Jquery for this solution.

```
  $('document').ready(function(){



  $('.tbdata').hover(
  function(){

        $(".tooltip").css("visibility","visible");
        $(".tooltip").attr("attrname","attrvalue"); //attribute
  },
  function(){

        $(".tooltip").css("visibility","hidden");
        $(".tooltip").attr("attrname","attrvalue"); //attribute

  }

  );

});
```

Here is example:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1sz51oz/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I had to make small changes to make this work. It was not showing the 'data-' attribute value inside DIV. So I updated the same. `$('.tbdata').hover(
    function() {
      var divcontents = $(this).attr('data-');
      $(".tooltip").css("visibility", "visible");
      $(".tooltip").html(divcontents);
    },
    function() {
      $(".tooltip").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  );
});
`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the `content` property dynamically on hover, however, you can use some "trickery" to hide a span and show another.

This example below shows how you can do just that. This, as far as I know, is the best solution for a non-JS implementation of dynamically changing a `div` content on hover

```css
.button{
  background:lightblue;
  width:200px;
}

.tooltip{
  background:red;
  width:200px;
}

.tooltip .before { display: block; }
.tooltip .after  { display: none;  }


.button:hover .tooltip{
  background:green;
}

/* Hide the `.before` and show the `.after` */
.button:hover .tooltip .before{ display:none;  }
.button:hover .tooltip .after { display:block; }
```

```html
<div class="button">
  Hover over me!
  <div class="tooltip"><span class="before">Turn nothing</span><span class="after">Into something</span></div>
</div>
```

To hide/show the content, you would also apply `display` property changes to the `.tooltip`. I've left both `div` visible for this demonstration, however, to show the changing content.